# Removing substrings from words that start with them.(in C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a small piece of code(function) that removes the substrings in a string only if the words of the string start with these substrings. Look what I've tried till now:

```
char *string="internship, is wonderful for people who like programming"
char *prefixes="intern wonder in pe"
char *delsubstr(char *string, const char *prefixes)

 {
 char *tokprefix;
 tokprefix=strtok(prefixes, " ");
 while(tokprefix)
    {
     size_t m = strlen(tokprefix);
     char *p = string;
     while ((p = strstr(p, tokprefix))!= NULL)
        { 

                {
                 char *q = p + m;
                 size_t n = strlen(q);
                 memmove(p, q, n + 1);
                 }
         }
     tokprefix=strtok(NULL, " ");
     }
 return string;
}
```

The prob with it is it removes the substrings from everywhere and I only what the substrings from the beginning to be removed. Also if "intern" and "in" substrings are present, I want the bigger one to be removed from the string, not the smaller one. Anyone got any ideas/suggestions? I think an if condition before the memmove could be enough, but I'm not sure.

Comment: BTW String literals are immutable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is right, you must copy your strings first. And, if you want the words to be treated as words you should tokenize that string too, in your program there is no notion of "beginig of" or "end of" because there are no words to work with.

Comment: either use char array or use strdup() function to edit your string.

Comment: use char-arrays instead of nativ String-literals like: char prefixes[]="intern wonder in pe";

Comment: _... it removes the substrings from everywhere_: `strstr` finds a string anywhere in another string. If you want to know whether your string starts with a certain prefix `p`, use `strncmp(str, p, strlen(p)) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

> I think an if condition before the memmove could be enough, but I'm
>   not sure.

Apart from the problem of modifying the prefixes string literal, which is dealt with in the comments above, you're approximately correct:

```
     while ((p = strstr(p, tokprefix))!= NULL)
        { 
            if (p > string && p[-1] != ' ') // not at beginning of word?
                ++p;                        // then just advance pointer
            else                            // else remove start of word
                {
                 …
```